# How do i concatenate these two grep regexes

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have these two grep regexes

```
grep -e '[Yy].*[Yy].[Ee][Ee]' first.txt
```

and

```
grep -e '[Ee][Ee].*[Yy].*[Yy]' first.txt
```

How do I concatenate these two into a single regex?

Comment: Same as [Need a hand with grep+regex](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/361329). I take it you're taking the same course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By.. concatenating the patterns?

```
grep -e '[Yy].*[Yy].[Ee][Ee][Ee][Ee].*[Yy].*[Yy]' first.txt
```

Or did you mean essentially doing a logical AND of the two patterns?

If the latter, you need to fake it, as while `grep` has built-in OR (`|`) and NOT (`-v`; `[^]`), it does not have a built-in AND.  One way is by piping the output of one `grep` into the other:

```
grep -e '[Yy].*[Yy].[Ee][Ee]' first.txt | grep '[Ee][Ee].*[Yy].*[Yy]'
```

The other way is to look for both patterns in series, in either order, with a logical OR (abbreviated for brevity):

```
grep -Ee 'pattern1.*pattern2|pattern2.*pattern1' input.txt
```

I find the first to be more succinct and easier to maintain.

Comment: aren't there a way to write both in single regex to get the same output which that i can get through both regees , i meant without AND and OR?

Comment: It you just want the output of both `grep`s with no correlation between the two, use `grep -e 'pattern1' -e 'pattern2' /path/to/input`.

Answer (score 2):

You can grep for both patterns at once by using `\|` between each pattern.

```
grep -e '[Yy].*[Yy].[Ee][Ee]'\|'[Ee][Ee].*[Yy].*[Yy]'
```